# Running code from python has different permission than from bash?

Tags: python, linux, bash, permissions, exec

#### First step

```
$ sudo adduser foo_user
$ mkdir /tmp/foo-user && chown foo_user:foo_user $_
$ sudo npm install -g less  # Install Node.js and NPM for this
$ echo ".box {color: red}" | sudo -u foo_user tee /tmp/foo-user/main.less
```

---

#### Python

```
$ sudo -u foo_user python -c "from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT;
                              print check_output(['/usr/local/bin/lessc',
                                                  '/var/lib/nginx/body/main.less'],
                                                  stderr=STDOUT, shell=True);"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/lessc', '/tmp/foo-user/main.less']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

---

#### Bash

```
$ sudo -u foo_user /usr/local/bin/lessc /tmp/foo-user/main.less >NULL && echo $?
```

```
0
```

Comment: Can you minimize your examples so they don't rely on packages and such. Maybe change the examples to `echo some_root_file` or summin'. In other words, can you make a *minimal*, *runnable* sample?

Comment: Okay, added runnable example.

Answer (score 3):

With `shell=True`, you must use a string, not a list of arguments.  This is likely causing your problems (which *may not be permission problems* — in fact, you only know that *`lessc` exits with `1` and not the reason for it*).

Also, in Python, you run the command.  In Bash, you run the command and redirect stdout to a **file named NULL** (did you mean `/dev/null`?).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. (removing `shell=True`). And yeah, meant: `/dev/null` (was thinking of `NUL` from Windows Batch).

Comment: Confirmed working from bash; but not from the .py file. `returned non-zero exit status 127`